# OpAmp Selection | Sine Wave Amplifier: 30 MHz, 30Vpp with 15V offset

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, inverting-amplifier, harmonics, signal-generator

I am currently working on amplifying the output sine wave of the TG5011 professional signal generator. Below are the specifications for the amplifier I am aiming to create:

- Power Supply: A single supply of either 30V or 36V
- Output Voltage: 30V peak-to-peak (30Vpp)
- DC Offset: 15V DC
- Bandwidth: 100kHz to 30MHz
- Input Voltage: 1V peak-to-peak (1Vpp)

To achieve this, I am employing four cascaded op-amps, configuring two dual op-amp ICs in an inverting configuration with a 15V DC bias (please refer to the attached image). The required slew rate should be a minimum of 3000V/μs, as calculated by the formula SR = 2·π·Vout·f.

However, I have encountered a challenge in realizing this amplifier. Up until now, I have utilized the LM7372, which boasts a bandwidth of 120MHz. I am employing a gain of 3kOhm/1.3kOhm = 2.3 for each stage, theoretically resulting in a bandwidth of approximately 52 MHz. This worked flawlessly for each IC individually, but when connected together, the second IC overheated and ultimately burned out. Upon further investigation, I discovered that the LM7372 has limitations in its output swing voltage, which caused excessive heating and damage to the second IC.

I attempted to use the LM6172 (GBWP = 100 MHz); however, the gain dropped significantly at 15 MHz. I also experimented with the LM7171, but connecting the ICs together produced a substantial amount of harmonics and distortion.

I am now unsure of what I may be doing incorrectly and which op-amp model would be suitable for my application. I had contemplated using Current Feedback Amplifier (CFA) op-amps, but they are not recommended for inverting configurations and may introduce stability issues.

Do you have any recommendations for an op-amp model that I can employ to achieve my goal? I have attached an image of the schematic I am using for all the op-amps and the PCB design layout.

Note. I am not using the filter in the schematic.

I sincerely appreciate your assistance in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.  Interesting question, but you don't specify the load impedance which will be placed on the output, or the required input impedance.  You also haven't stated the allowable distortion.  Without these you amplifier isn't sufficiently specified to verify the integrity of the overall design.

Comment: Just some quick thoughts. Have you tried powering the OPAMPs using dual supplies (e.g. +/-15V)? I am aware of your design requirements, however, I have faced erratic behaviour when attempting to amplify AC signals with single supplies (Vcc/GND) even with "single supply" capable OPAMPs. Additionally, 15V BIAS sounds a bit too high for me, however, I need to carefully study the datasheets.

Comment: You won't get 30 volts p-p from a 30 volt supply.

Comment: NB: the midpoint (R19-R22) is NOT "really"  15 V. You must use an "opamp follower" to make it true.

Comment: @colintd Thanks. 

The load impedance will be an open electrical wire to perform frequency sweeps and detect some parameters. Therefore the load can be interpreted as high impedance, almost all resistive with some parasitic capacitance. I am measuring with a scope of x10 (10 MOhm and ~14pF). Professional oscilloscope: PicoScope 3206DMSO. 

Relative to the input impedance, I am not sure what you mean. The output impedance of the generator is 50Ohm, and will be 200Ohm when I will use the AD9850 IC.

Relative to the allowable distortion, I did not thing about it.

Comment: @DanielMelendrez Hi. I didn't try to use them with +/-15V supply. I should create another PCB because using a breadboard will be a terrible idea. Therefore I cannot assure if it is working properly with dual supply.

Comment: @Andyaka Hi, you are right. My bad, these op amps are not rail-to-rail. They achieve more or less 24 Vpp (+12Vp and -12Vp). I have been working with them at that output. I have tried looking for a rail-to-rail high speed opamps but I didn't find anyone with a slew rate.

Comment: @Antonio51 Hi. When I measure it gives me 15V DC. And the output signal has the 15V DC offset, with its tiny variation.

Comment: Given the frequency range, I am not convinced the load is a "high impedance".  If the load has a capacitance of 14pF, then my quick calc suggests an impedance of ~400R at 30MHz (1/2pi.f.C).  At 30V, this equates to a current of ~75mA.  If there is extra parasitic capacitance, then the current requirement will be significantly higher.

Comment: @colintd You are right. However that is something I cannot avoid, no? Is there any way of reduce the parallel capacitance without using a very expensive.

Comment: Make sure the ceramic caoacitors that touch the signal are C0G types. Check their self resonant frequency. Watch out for the midpoint bias distribution. The way that it is implemented connects all the IN+ pins together. Use a voltage divider on each op-amp instead.

Comment: I'm not saying you need to change the load, just that you need to recognize you are trying to design an amp that will deliver a significant current into a capacitive load.  As with the intermediate amp stages, you need to think about not just the voltage gain, but also the current load.  For instance, your final opamp has a 1K resistor to ground.  Ignoring the load from the transistors or feedback, this alone is going to draw a peak current of 30mA at 30V, and the OpAmps are only rated for 50mA per channel.

Comment: You should see something like this https://www.apexanalog.com/resources/products/pa107u.pdf

Comment: Agree with previous commenter.  Use a dedicated power opamp

Comment: @RussellH Hi. All the capacitors are C0G types, except for C16 and C17 which are tantalum (op-amp manufacturer recommendation). I am using ceramic capacitors from these 0805 SMD Capacitor Books (1% precision), which you can find on Amazon, AliExpress, or eBay. When measured with a professional LCR meter (Keysight U1732C), the actual values closely match the indicated values. However, because they are not purchased from formal suppliers like Farnell, RS, Mouser..., maybe they contribute degrading the performance of the PCB.

Thanks for the tips. I will add a voltage divider for each op-amp.

Comment: @Antonio51@colintd Thanks, I will investigate this family of op-amps.

Comment: **Update.**

Since PA107U family is too expensive for me, I will try to use CFA op-amps like: THS3062, THS3092, THS3096... They are more affordable and some of them often used in applications like: High-Voltage Arbitrary Wavefrom and/or Test and Measurement Systems.

Thanks for the comments.